# Regarding jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to display all the elements which have been checked.

By using this code i tried to push all the checked elements to array1.

```
    var array1 = new Array();  
$(':checkbox').is(':checked').each(function()

        { //control not coming here
  array1.push($(this));
 }
 ); 
     alert("hi");
```

How to display the array1 contents .Thanks in advance.
NOTE  :  check the comments

Comment: What exactly do you want to display? The array contains jQuery objects, so what should the output be? And actually, there is not need to push them to an array. Depending on what you want to do, you can just use: `var array1 = $(':checked');` (not saying that using `:checked` is the best way).

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do:

```
var obj = $(":checkbox:checked");
```

...and then show the contents of the `obj` object. jQuery instances are very much like arrays. They have a `length` property, and numeric indexes that will give you the underlying DOM element at that index. E.g.:

```
var obj = $(":checkbox:checked");
var n;

for (n = 0; n < obj.length; ++n) {
    show(obj[n]); // `show` will receive ehe DOM element
}
```

You'll frequently see the above written like this, though:

```
$(":checkbox:checked").each(function() {
    show(this);
});
```

...because jQuery instances have an `each` function that will call your callback for each element in the object. More in [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/each/) (although jquery.com is having issues today; [here's a link](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aAZDSdrvCPYsJ%3aapi.jquery.com/each/%20jquery%20each%20api%20doc&cd=3&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk&source=www.google.co.uk) to the cached version on Google).

Answer (score 0):

toSource() can help u to do so

```
var arraytest = array1.toSource()
alert(arraytest)
```

Comment: `toSource` is a Firefox extension, it most likely does not exist in other browsers.